# How to return only 3 elements from arrays of object in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary, object

So, I basically use Github User API, fetching 30 of users via Axios, and display it as a list, but I want it to be shown only 3 of them, how can it be done? Should I try to trick on map function or something at fetching section?

Tried to do some tricks on map or filter functions but end up with failure.

```
 state = {
    users: [],
    loading: false,
    alert: null
  };



searchUser = async text => {
this.setState({ loading: true });

const res = await axios.get(
  `https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${text}&client_id=${
    process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID
  }&client_secret=${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET}`
);

this.setState({ users: res.data.items, loading: false });
  };
```

---

```
{users.map(
<UserItem key={user.id} user={user} />
        ))}
```

Comment: Github offers a query parameter to limit per page. `per_page=3`. https://api.github.com/search/users?q=facebook&per_page=3. `Array.slice` also works as mentioned below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) will limit the array to only include the first `x` elements.  If there is less than `x` elements in the array it will simply leave the array as-is:

```
{
  users.slice(0, 3).map(
    <UserItem key={user.id} user={user} />
  ))
}
```

Another issue you may be running into is not using the `user` data from the state:

```
{
  this.state.users.slice(0, 3).map(
    <UserItem key={user.id} user={user} />
  ))
}
```

You can read more about [React state here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

Edit: As pointed out by [@ChristopherNgo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10030970/christopher-ngo)  [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) is non-inclusive so it should be 0 to 3 for 3 elements.

Comment: You need `users.slice(0, 3)` since for slice the 2nd parameter is not-inclusive.

Comment: @ChristopherNgo Thanks you are right, I missed that.  Updated post to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

After storing the values in the state object in `users` attribute fetched as `res`:

```
...

const res = await axios.get(
  `https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${text}&client_id=${
    process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID
  }&client_secret=${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET}`
);

this.setState({ users: res.data.items, loading: false });
  };
```

The code below must give you your desired result of `3 elements from array of objects`

```
let SIZE = 3;
let users = this.state.users.slice(0, SIZE).map(item => {
    return <UserItem item={item} key={item.id} />
}

...

return (
  <div>
    {users}
  </div>   
)
```

Answer (score 0):

//for functional components

```
const [users, setUsers] = usestate([ ]);

return (
 
    users.slice(0, 3).map( item => {
        ...add logic
    })
)
```